# Agg Functions while Partitioning Data in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that looks like this:

```
store_id   industry_id   cust_id   amount   gender
1          100           1000      1.00     M
2          100           1000      2.05     M
3          100           1000      3.15     M
4          100           1000      4.00     M
5          100           2000      5.00     F
6          200           2000      5.20     F
7          200           5000      6.05     F
8          200           6000      7.10     F
```

Here's the code to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    store_id int,
    industry_id int,
    cust_id int,
    amount float,
    gender char
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,100,1000,1.00, 'M');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,100,1000,2.05, 'M');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3,100,1000,3.15, 'M');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4,100,1000,4.00, 'M');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(5,100,2000,5.00, 'F');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(6,200,2000,5.20, 'F');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(7,200,5000,6.05, 'F');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(8,200,6000,7.10, 'F');
```

The question I'm trying to answer is: *What is the avg. transaction amount for the top 20% of customers by industry?*

This should yield these results:

```
store_id.     industry_id      avg_amt_top_20
1             100              4.80
2             100              4.80
3             100              4.80
4             100              4.80
5             100              4.80
6             200              7.10
7             200              7.10
8             200              7.10
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
store_id, industry_id,
avg(CASE WHEN percentile>=0.80 THEN amount ELSE NULL END) OVER(PARTITION BY industry_id)  as cust_avg
FROM(
    SELECT store_id, industry_id, amount, cume_dist() OVER(
        PARTITION BY industry_id 
        ORDER BY amount desc) AS percentile 
    FROM t1
) tmp
GROUP BY store_id, industry_id;
```

This fails on the GROUP BY (contains nonaggregated column 'amount'). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I am unclear why `store_id` is in the results for the question that is being asked.

Comment: I kept store_id in the results because I'll need to look up the results using the store_id in other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the avg. transaction amount for the top 20% of customers by industry?

Based on this question, I don't see why `store_id` is in the results.

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate to get the total by customer.  Then you can use `NTILE()` to determine the top 20%.  The final step is aggregating by industry:

```
SELECT industry_id, AVG(total)
FROM (SELECT customer_id, industry_id, SUM(amount) as total,
             NTILE(5) OVER (PARTITION BY industry_id ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) as tile
      FROM t
      GROUP BY customer_id, industry_id
     ) t
WHERE tile = 1
GROUP BY industry_id
```